# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path.'

Tags: vb.net

I want to copy a file from my resource in a project, and I have the directory target, here's the code:

```
Private Sub Frm_Stat_Load(...) Handles Mybase.Load

    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(Script_Path_DiskPArt) Then
            CreateDirectory(Script_Path_DiskPArt)
    Else

    End If
    ...

End Sub

Private Sub MakeVDISK()

    System.IO.FIle.WriteAllBytes(Script_Path_DiskPart, My.Resources.MakeVDISK1)'This is the line where the exception occurs
    ...

End Sub
```

`Script_Path_Diskpart` contains a string constant; `"C:\Temp\Me.TemporalDrive\"`

I am getting the following exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Temp\Me.TemporalDrive\'.

Comment: Which line of code gives the error ?

Comment: Why is there a period at the end of the path, but inside of the quotation mark? Does this path actually exist on your machine? Do you actually have a folder named `Me.TemporalDrive`?

Comment: Step through the code. Hold the cursor over the variable `Script_Path_DiskPArt` - Copy and paste it's value into the Windows Explorer directory bar - I'll bet that the path doesn't exist. It's strange you have a . in the folder name, and also there's the `\'.'` at the end of the variable in the error message.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya on line 14

Comment: @CodyGray The `CreateDirectory(Script_Path_DiskPArt)` creates the directory named "Me.TemporalDrive" in "C:\Temp\"

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya `WriteAllBytes(Script_Path_DiskPart, My.Resources.MakeVDISK1)`

Comment: @David Works fine on Explorer...

Comment: Got that... Did you verify if the directory is actually being created during `Form_Load` ? Can you share the code of method `WriteAllBytes` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, it creates the directory named "Me.TemporalDrive" during load. I use `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes`, I'm sorry I didn't explained at that point

Comment: [WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) expects a file path as the first argument not a directory.

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` expects as file path as first argument, not the directory path. You need to provide a complete file path like `C:C:\Temp\Me.Temporal\somefile.txt`.

Comment: @CodyGray and @David The period is from the exception message. Imagine with brackets instead: `Exception { Path not found { yourpath }. }`

Comment: @Bugs is right... I forgot to add the filename from a path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Script_Path_DiskPart = "C:\Temp\Me.TemporalDrive\", with this line:
`System.IO.FIle.WriteAllBytes(Script_Path_DiskPart, My.Resources.MakeVDISK1)`
you're trying to write your bytes to a directory and not to a file.

This should work:

`System.IO.FIle.WriteAllBytes(Script_Path_DiskPart & "file.bin", My.Resources.MakeVDISK1)`